# setting priors in bipf function in r

Tags: r

I am trying to set priors for the bipf function form the cat package. This function runs Schafer's (1997) Bayesian Iterative Proportional Fitting.

My crosstab has three binary variables (A,B,C),

```
data<-matrix(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=300),nrow=100,ncol=3)

colnames(data)<-c(A,B,C)

freq<-xtabs(~data[,1]+data[,2]+data[,3])
```

In bipf we are sampling from a posterior gamma with shape parameter (here is link),
[image: Schafer shape parameter]

Where x is the cell frequency, and alpha is the cell hyperparameter.

I want to set the priors so that we are sampling from a posterior gamma distribution where with shape parameter is,
[image: shape parameter wanted]

So I want the sum of the prior hyperparameters to equal 1.

As I have 3 binary variables I set the priors equal to 0.5 (1/2), as with three variables we have two crosstabs (split across the third variable).

```
freq

priors<-0.5

bipftheta<-bipf(freq,c(1,2,0,1,3),start=freq,prior=priors,steps=1,showits=FALSE)
```

Am I setting the priors correctly to get the final shape parameters I want?